# SQL Different Performance on Different Machines

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two different machines running SQL server 2017 Developer Edition based instances on both machines. Both Machines have 100% same SQL server engine structure (Tables, Views, SP, Indexes etc.) but on different Machine specs.
Here are the Specs:

Machines-1 (Laptop machine)
RAM: 12 GB (100% allocated to SQL)
Processor: Intel Core i7-7500U 2.7GHz
Storage: SSD 500GB
OS: Windows 10 Pro

Machine-2 (Desktop Machine)
RAM: 32 GB (100% allocated to SQL)
Processor: Intel Xeon Silver 4110CPU 2.10GHz
Storage: M.2 for OS and HDD for SQL Server
OS: Windows Server 2016

Problem I'm facing right now is, Same queries and SPs are taking much much higher time on Machine-2 than Machine-1.
Maximum query processing time against a complex query on Machine-1 was 25 minutes, which is 1.5 hour on Machine-2.

Please please help me to fix this performance problem as this is heavily impacting the day to day operations.

Comment: I am almost certain that the problem is one of the following:  (1) the machines are configured differently for SQL Server; (2) the data is different on the two machines; (3) the data structure/database options are different.  You'll argue that they are the same, however, until you find the problem.

Comment: Different data sizes and different statistics will result in different execution plans and different performance. Even 25 minutes is too much though. What does the query do? Are there missing indexes? Constructs that *prevent* the use of indexes?

Comment: Thanks for your response guys. Daily data size to be processed is same as it was earlier even indexes are there. Please just let me know what to share with you experts to analyze it or help me what to compare between two instances to get the root cause.

Comment: Sorry, that's far too broad for StackOverflow.  You haven't mentioned, for example, if other uses are working on Machine2.  You haven't mentioned if the logging level is different on the two machines.  This is probably better suited to a different site altogether.  (Such as dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I'm working on both machines all alone and both machines are running with same domain user which is me. I've moved all data from machine1 to machine2 as laptop is not a suitable machine to run SQL server.

Comment: If the "fast" machine is taking nearly a minute and a half to run a query I would suggest that perhaps the query itself needs some attention. That is mighty slow for any normal use query. At the very least posting the execution plans for the query from both machines would be a big help. As it sits right now this is not answerable.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff please help me how to find problem?

Comment: Guys, one situation that I have observed through Task Manager is, when I execute same SP on machine1, both memory and CPU usage got increased above 90% and 60% respectively but when I execute same SP on machine2, only memory usage reach upto 90% whereas CPU usage remain under 3%. For both machines, memory and CPU allocation is set on default SQL configurations.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't set memory allocation to 100% for SQL Server, you need to leave some space to your OS or everything will suffer.

You might also have problems with parallelism that might be using more processors than actually needed. You'll see lots of CXPACKET waits as a result of this. Adjust you maximum degree of parallelism based on the following [Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-max-degree-of-parallelism-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017)

- **Server with single NUMA node & less than 8 logical processors**    Keep MAXDOP at or below # of logical processors
- **Server with single NUMA node & Greater than 8 logical processors** Keep MAXDOP at 8
- **Server with multiple NUMA nodes & Less than 8 logical processors** per NUMA node   Keep MAXDOP at or below # of logical processors per NUMA node
- **Server with multiple NUMA nodes & Greater than 8 logical processors** per NUMA node    Keep MAXDOP at 8

You also need to configure the [Cost Threshold for Parallelism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-cost-threshold-for-parallelism-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017) as the default is too low for real problems.

Finally, you need to consider that your data on the laptop is on a SSD, but the data on the desktop is on a HDD. That will make a huge difference on how fast the data is retrieved and processed.

I'm not sure if there's something else that can be addressed. Make sure your statistics are created and up to date on both places, and index maintenance is being run.

Answer (score 0):

- use max memory cap for sql server
- ssd and hdd can make a lot of difference in IO
- The two machine can have different sql configuration
- There can be other process running in these machines, for example, anti virus application can scan the mdf and tempdb,  if sql server is not excluded in settings

To quickly find out what's different in these two machines,

### Run a health check with Sp_Blitz

- Run *sp_blitz* [sp] (https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit#sp_blitz-overall-health-check) to see what is actually causing your performance bottleneck .
- check for priorities from 1to 50, those are most crucial.
- start fixing them one by one